# C programming: Check that each character is a valid number between 0 and 9, ignoring formatting characters

Tags: arrays, c, character

I am a beginner at coding and am currently in a course for this. I have been asked to produce a program that has a special function to convert the timestamps in a file into something that can be sorted from earliest to latest based on a numerical value. These would be imported from a file into an array.  Some points of the assignment are:

1. The array of strings should be allocated dynamically to minimise the amount of memory used.
2. Create a function called timeStampToSeconds() that converts a timestamp string to a long int, which represents the number of seconds elapsed since 01/01/2000 00:00:00.
3. Your code will need to check that each character is a valid number between 0 and 9, ignoring formatting characters ('/', ' ', ':', '-') and convert the characters to their equivalent integers before being used to calculate the number of seconds elapsed since the above starting point.

I have included my code but am wondering if anyone has any pointers to help me on point 2 & 3? I have started with trying to implement point 3 with the strtok function, but I think I may be way off on this.Curently my function prototype is not doing what I had hoped for this.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 50

void timeStampToSeconds(char array[]);

int main(void)
{

  char array[50][20];
  char input[10], filename[] = "Timestamps", outputfile[40], file_ext[4] = ".dat";
  int i = 0, n = 0, j, x = 0, y = 0, o = 0;
  double datetime = 0;



  while (*input != *filename) {
      printf("\nPlease enter the names of the required Input file: \n");
      scanf("%s", input);


      if (*input == *filename) {

          printf("Input accepted!\n");
      }
      else printf("File name not found.Please try again!\n");

  }


  printf("Please enter the name of the sorted Output file to be created: \n");
  scanf("%s", &outputfile);
  strncat(&outputfile, &file_ext, 4);  /*appends file extension characters to outputfile 
 variable characters*/

  FILE* Ptr = NULL;
  FILE* cfPtr = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));


  if ((cfPtr = fopen("Timestamps.dat", "r")) == NULL) {
    printf("File could not be opened\n");
  }




  while (!feof(cfPtr))
  {
      for (i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
      {
          for (j = 0; j < 20; ++j)
          {
              array[x][j] = fgetc(cfPtr);
              y++;
          }
          x++;
      }
  }

  fclose(cfPtr);

  timeStampToSeconds(array);

  if ((Ptr = fopen(outputfile, "w")) == NULL) {
      printf("File could not be opened\n");
  }



  fwrite(array, sizeof(char), sizeof(array), Ptr);
  fclose(Ptr);

  return 0;
}

void timeStampToSeconds(char array[])
{
  array;
  long int n = 0, j = 0;
  const char a[2] = "/"; const char b[2] = "-";
  const char c[2] = ":";
  char* token; char* token2; char *token3;


  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE - 1; ++i) {
      token = strtok(array, a);
      while (token != NULL) {
          token = strtok(NULL, a);
      }
      token2 = strtok(token, b);
      while (token2 != NULL) {
          token2 = strtok(NULL, b);
      }
      token3 = strtok(token2, c);
      while (token3 != NULL) {
          token3 = strtok(NULL, c);
      }
      token3 = array;
  }



  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE - 1; ++i) {
      n = atol(array[i]);
      array[i] = n;
  }

}
```

Comment: Aside: note that `file_ext[4] = ".dat"` isn't a nul-terminated C string. Please use `file_ext[] = ".dat"` to allow the compiler to terminate it automatically.

Comment: Please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Note that `if (*input == *filename)` only compares the first character (use `strcmp`) and also note that `char input[10]` is dangerously short, particularly without any length restriction such as `scanf("%9s", input);`. Your variable can't even hold `"Timestamps"` so the program is broken even before trying to compare it.

Comment: allocating memory for cfPtr is a memory leak : fip en return a pointer to some structure which has been allocated.

Comment: The timestamp to seconds should take a string as input and return a long int . It should check of each character is either a separator or a between ‘0’ and ‘9’ corresponding to year,month,day,… . Convert a char between ‘0’ and ‘9’ to numerical value is just doing : character-‘0’ (‘0’ is a one byte integer containing the ascii code of ‘0’. BTW, when you loop while token not NULL, after the loop token is NULL . So strtok(token,b) will not work as you imagine.

Comment: What happens in your code if less that SIZE (aka 50) time stamp in your input file ?

Comment: when commpiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedandic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results